# Sublime Text Colored Comment Lines for all file types

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

When I write PHP my comment lines between stars are hot pink. This may be a plugin feature but I am not sure which one.

This is very convenient when using the mini map for orienting around a big file.

Does anyone know how to get this functionality across all file types that support /* comments */?

[image]

Comment: what color scheme are you using?

Comment: @MattDMo https://github.com/kkga/spacegray

Comment: Does it do the same with comments like `/* … */`? In PHP, comments starting with `/**` can be annotations. I guess It is why your Sublime treats them differently.

Comment: @Einenlum youre right its the /** that makes the difference. Looks like its sublimelinter thats giving this ability in PHP.